# When wiring a switch loop, which wire is which?

Tags: electrical, wiring

If you're wiring up a lighting circuit, where the power enters at the lighting outlet. According to the National Electrical Code, which wire should be "hot" and which should be "switched hot"?

#### Question in graphical form:

[image: Graphical Representation of Question]

<sub>*Bonus points if you can reference relevant code section(s).*</sub>

Comment: Personally, I make black the always hot, and white with black tape the switched hot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It doesn't matter, it's in the past

In the old days (pre 2011 code adoption), National Electrical Code said that if a wire with white or gray insulation or a marking of three white or gray continuous stripes is used as part of a switch loop to single-pole, 3-way, or 4-way switches. The conductor should be permanently reidentified, and should be used for the supply to the switch but not the return (200.7(C)(2)).

> ## National Electrical Code 2008
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 200 Use and Identification of Grounded Conductors
>
> **200.7 Use of Insulation of a White or Gray Color or
>   with Three Continuous White Stripes.**
>
> (2) Where a cable assembly contains an insulated conductor
>   for single-pole, 3-way or 4-way switch loops and
>   the conductor with white or gray insulation or a marking
>   of three continuous white stripes is used for the
>   supply to the switch but not as a return conductor from
>   the switch to the switched outlet. In these applications,
>   the conductor with white or gray insulation or with
>   three continuous white stripes shall be permanently reidentified
>   to indicate its use by painting or other effective
>   means at its terminations and at each location
>   where the conductor is visible and accessible.

So before 2011 NEC adoption, the wiring should look like this.

[image: Proper switch loop wiring]

## The future

According to the 2011 code...

> ## National Electrical Code 2011
>
> ### Chapter 4 Equipment for General Use
>
> #### ARTICLE 404 Switches
>
> **I. Installation**
>
> **404.2 Switch Connections.**
>
> **(C) Switches Controlling Lighting Loads.** Where switches control lighting loads supplied by a grounded general purpose branch circuit, a grounded circuit conductor shall be provided at the switch location.

A grounded (neutral) conductor is now required at each switch location (see code for exceptions), which means the circuit would now have to look like this...

[image]

Or

[image]

Comment: So you leave the neutral capped off in the box?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, yes or used in lighted, smart, etc. switches that require power.

Comment: Either is correct but it's sort of a convention to, when an always-hot and switched-hot are present, make black always and red switched.  I even put a piece of red tape on the black lead from the lamp, so it really is "match color to color".

Answer (score 2):

It is still in the 2017 Code. 200.7 (C) (1) requires the white used as ungrounded (hot), in a switch loop, to be re-identified with another color.