# What is the proper way to wire a light switch,fan switch and receptacle in one box?

Tags: wiring

I would like to see a wiring diagram on how to wire two switches and a receptacle in one box with a single line feed, three wires.

Comment: Assuming modern wiring, a single line with 3 wires in it can only be for a single switch. You can't have an outlet and two switches.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you're trying to use a single cable with only 3 wires, one of the switches will do nothing.

[image]

Comment: As Tester101 illustrates, you need a common hot **to** the switches and a separate switched hot **from** the switches. That always equals 3 wires to control the hots. If you were not also putting an outlet in that box, you would not need a neutral (for basic switches) and could get by with a three wire, using the white as one of the hots, but correctly marked, and assuming there is a neutral at the fixture. Once you introduce an active device (the outlet), you need at least four wires, whether in one or more cables (and green/bare is not counted).

Comment: @bib As of NEC 2011 a grounded (neutral) conductor is required at switches too (though there are some exceptions). See [Article 404.2 (C)](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/31710/33)

Comment: Excellent point and I think you've told me this before.  Lets hope it sinks in this time.