# 2 wire source + an outlet + 2 separate lights w/2 switches

Tags: wiring

We are redoing the outside washer/dryer room, and the builder has removed the wiring from the outlets/switches and we are having a hard time reinstalling everything as it was before.
The setup uses 2 switches and an outlet. One switch is for the patio-feeding two bulbs, the second switch, is for the washer/dyer room light. The outlet is for the washer/dryer.
So, we have a 2 wire(black, white and green) from the panel coming into the room.
Inside the room, I have an outlet that feeds the washer and dryer, and a light in the ceiling. This light is switched by one of the switches.
We also have two lights for the patio, that is switched from the second switch.
I'm handy enough to connect everything safely. I just can't find a diagram with this specific setup.
Actually I have found one, but does not show the lights in that diagram.
[What is the proper way to wire a light switch,fan switch and receptacle in one box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32802/what-is-the-proper-way-to-wire-a-light-switch-fan-switch-and-receptacle-in-one-b)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the wiring between panel and laundry room?  Could you run another circuit if you had to?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a proper way to put it in a single box. You need a double or triple wide box, depending on the switches you pick. Switches can be purchased in one up or two up per assembly. I am assuming the wall is not finished, if it is it is a much bigger problem, in either case you will have to replace the box with a bigger one. Check at your local box store, they will help you select the correct parts. You need to put the light on one switch, the fan on the second (assuming on and off only), and the power goes to the duplex and the two switches. All white neturals have to be connected together. Before you begin you need to determine where each of the wires go. If you cannot do that and do not have the resources to trace the wiring get a friend that can help you. I am assuming you are in the USA, other countries may be different.

Comment: The original question doesn't say anything about whether this is a single or double or triple box.

Comment: Actually there will be 2 circuits required since it is being rewired. The laundry circuit is required to be a 20 amp the lighting / and additional receptacles can be a 15 or 20 amp. I am not sure where you get your statement from as far as I can tell the question was focused on 120v and single boxes may be fine at each location

Comment: Since there are 2 switches and an outlet, it cannot possibly be a single box.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help, it is much appreciated.
This job had warranty and I just chickened out, and called back the electrician.
Thank you again for everybody.

Comment: Smart move! Always better to be safe. Watch and ask questions, the next time something comes up you will be better equipped to work with it.