# Do electricians often/frequently interchange the color on the grounded leg when wiring switches?

Tags: electrical, nec

A recent comment on [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62979/trying-to-replace-outlet-puzzled#comment87164_62979) said that it was not unusual to see the grounded leg of a switched circuit being used as the switched leg, there was some agreement.

This seems a terrifying problem if true.

For me, this was learned in the first week of working in the trade.

I could never have passed a rough-in inspection for something like this the day after a hurricane, of a latrine, at a campground in Florida, where he was so drunk someone else had to drive the golf cart.

Does this really happen often?

---

I removed my answer that spoke of NEC 404.2(B) due to comments by a user that did not think that a citation of, what is law, in some jurisdictions, was relevent to the question. The argument could be made that this perspective is/was reasonable.

Comment: I think you mean the neutral leg, which is distinct from the ground (even though neutral and ground and bonded at the service panel, they are still distinct circuits and are not interchangeable)

Comment: Distinct from the ground - true. This is about the - Grounded Leg - I am speaking of the neutral, as they are bonded at 1 point in the circuit.

Comment: They are separate wires and should be treated as separate circuits. Using the ground wire as the return path of a switched circuit is definitely not permitted. The fact that they are (well should be) bonded at the service panel doesn't make them interchangeable. You should clarify your question one way or another because the answer is different between using the ground wire and neutral wire in a switched circuit, ground must not be switched.

Comment: Maybe you misinterpreted what I meant in my comment that you are referring to. I was simply saying that a white wire doesn't always mean neutral, and a black wire doesn't always mean hot.  A red wire can be neutral or hot too. It's just the color of the insulation.  Ideally the person would mark it appropriately but there is nothing requiring it.

Comment: NEC 404.2B says that switches shouldn't switch the neutral. It doesn't say that they can't switch a hot wire that just happens to be a white wire.

Comment: @SomeGuy - I didn't say the NEC was not applicable, you did in your comment on the answer, you said that the question referred to Canada or maybe Mexico and you didn't think the NEC applied. I said that an answer that only refers to the code (any code) does not answer your question of _Does this really happen often_. The fact that something is permitted (or prohibited) by code doesn't address whether or not it's commonly encountered in practice (many things that used to be permitted by code are commonly encountered even if they are no longer allowed under current codes)

Comment: @steve I might have, it would not be the first time, today. I specifically did not speak of you by name, or the wire by color. I am sure there are hundreds of examples jurisdictional law among the trades every day. I know I have gone back and changed my work after passing an inspection, simply because it was in violation of code. People that care enough to ask and answer here likely produce superior work, simply because they care enough to get into the mix. It takes a special person to take pride in work that will be hidden in a wall.

Comment: Having to correct the work, of those who do not understand electricity well enough to switch the hot leg, and knowing the work is out there

Comment: There are too many that do not understand grounding and bonding. As far as wire colors, I have little doubt that 75% of the THHN sold is black. Using split phase service in the USA powering something using a double pole breaker and 2 wire cable will land a white wire on a breaker almost every time. No grounded conductor, it is the way things are done. It is easy for someone to see that, to think either using either wire for a switch leg is fine. Is it done, yes. '2 phase' with 'single-phase' and 'split-phase' are viewed as the same way too often. Hot leg, Grounded leg also has this problem.

Comment: @SomeGuy - I don't understand that comment - are you saying that there are some cases where a Neutral wire (i.e. white) that leads back to the panel (as opposed to leading to a switched device) is not ultimately grounded at the service panel? Is there ever a case where the white wire is permitted to be connected to the hot output of a breaker?

Comment: @Johnny -  White wires are allowed to be landed on a breaker, yes - that is what I am saying. It is dangerous to associate white wires as being neutral wires. Indeed my question was to ask how often neutral lines are used as switched lines, with the exception of a disconnect. Disconnects are distinctly different from switchs. To the best of my knowledge, it is intended that the output side of a breaker will be hot, the exceptions being when the breaker has tripped, or turned off.

Comment: @Johnny, don't have the time to read *all* those comments but SomeGuy is correct in his terminology. A neutral is "the" ground-*ed* **not** ground-*ing* wire which is the "ground" (green/bare) wire. They are distinct but not in the way you suggest.

Comment: Ground**ed** is the neutral wire, and the current-carrying conductor that is at ground potential (by the power of the ground/neutral bond, at one point.) Ground**ing** is the "safety" connection, and should **never** carry current when there is not a fault condition.

Answer (score 3):

Not all grounded conductors are white, and not all white conductors are grounded conductors.

There's no problem using a white or gray wire as an ungrounded conductor, as long as the conductor is permanently reidentified.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 200 Use and Identification of Grounded Conductors
>
> **200.7 Use of Insulation of a White or Gray Color or
>   with Three Continuous White Stripes.**
>
> **(C) Circuits of 50 Volts or More.** The use of insulation
>   that is white or gray or that has three continuous white or gray
>   stripes for other than a grounded conductor for circuits
>   of 50 volts or more shall be permitted only as in (1)
>   and (2).
>
> (1) If part of a cable assembly that has the insulation permanently
>   reidentified to indicate its use as an ungrounded
>   conductor by marking tape, painting, or other
>   effective means at its termination and at each location
>   where the conductor is visible and accessible. Identification
>   shall encircle the insulation and shall be a color
>   other than white, gray, or green. If used for single-pole,
>   3-way or 4-way switch loops, the reidentified conductor
>   with white or gray insulation or three continuous
>   white or gray stripes shall be used only for the supply
>   to the switch, but not as a return conductor from the
>   switch to the outlet.

There **is** a problem with switching the grounded conductor, but no problem switching a white conductor (as long as it's reidentified).

> ### Chapter 4 Equipment for General Use
>
> #### Article 404 Switches
>
> **404.2 Switch Connections.**
>
> **(B) Grounded Conductors.** Switches or circuit breakers
>   shall not disconnect the grounded conductor of a circuit.
>
> *Exception: A switch or circuit breaker shall be permitted
>   to disconnect a grounded circuit conductor where all circuit
>   conductors are disconnected simultaneously, or where
>   the device is arranged so that the grounded conductor cannot
>   be disconnected until all the ungrounded conductors of
>   the circuit have been disconnected.*

Before the introduction of [404.2(C)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/31710/33), two wire switch loops were common. Since a two wire cable only has a black and white wire (and ground sometimes), the white wire had to be reidentified and used as an ungrounded conductor.

Comment: Sidenote: 404.2(C) is the neutral-in-the-switch-box clause that was added recently to support timers, motion sensors, and other "smart" devices

Answer (score 0):

A switch should always switch the hot conductor (NEC 404.2(B) that you referenced), so I'll assume you're talking about the side of the switch that is not electrified when the switch is off.

In a lot of cases, an electrician won't have an option in the matter, they will use the conductors available.  Lets say you have a switch that does not have the line coming into it the box (comes in at the ceiling fixture, for example), but rather its just a 14/2 cable from the ceiling box to the switch box (I know the most recent code requires a 14/3 so there is a dedicated neutral, but that's another story). In this case, they have a switch, and a cable with a black, white and bare conductor.  The white conductor is going to have to be used to complete the circuit.

In the best case, the electrician would wrap black electrical tape around the white wire on both sides so you know it is hot, but there's still nothing wrong with using the white colored wire for this.

Some dimmer switches I've bought have white, black and blue wires on them. Again, it doesn't mean anything, it's just a way to identify which wire is which on the schematic. If I drive around my neighborhood, all the transformers have 3 black wires coming off of them. Some of them have white tape wrapped on them, some of them don't.  No linesman is going to just assume its one or the other by looking at it.